# c++ factory pattern

Tags: c++, factory-pattern

I am sorry for the long text but I would like to present the problem I am trying to solve with this as well as the actual problem. Maybe I will be pointed to another, possibly better approach.

I would like to create an eventtriggerred handler system. I will have several handler modules. The basic idea is that during initialization these modules will register for events they handle (register(module,eventItGetsCalledFor)) in a eventlist. In the case an event is triggered, it is looked up in the eventlist and all modules listed there are created and run. To achieve this all the modules have an interface.

My two questions are:

1. Since I only want to instantiate the modules upon the actual event I need either a way to store a pointer to the constructor ("virtual constructor"), since there are no virtual constructors as far as I know I go with a Factory method which I would like to add to the interface. The classic approach I know of would be:

   ```
   class myInterface {
   public:
      ...
      static virtual *myInterface builder() = 0; //is static (pure) virtual possible?
   };

   class example : public myInterface {
   public:
      ...
      static virtual *myInterface builder() { return new example(); }
   };
   ```

   I would then have to store pointers to the builder() functions in the event list and execute the functions in case the event occurs to create the objects. I am wondering if there is a way arround writing `static virtual *myInterface builder() { return new example(); }` for every example module.
   A template approach would be to put it like this:

   template 
   static virtual *myInterface builder() { return new T(); }

   However I dont like it to much since I would have to write the following to register a module for an event:

   register(eventName,builder())

   considering that I would like to create only one static register function in each module like so:

   ```
   class example: public myInterface {
       static void registerMe {
           register(event1,builder<example>());
           register(event2,builder<example>());
           ...
           register(eventn,builder<example>());
       }
   };
   ```

   it would be way more convenient if a call like `register(event)` would be sufficient.
   i could add `register(event)` to the interface, but I dont want to rewrite the register function for every template which would read

   ```
   void register(event) { getListForEvent(event).pushBack(builder<example>()); }
   ```

   (the builder-template instantiation parameter varies), and making it a template itself is not to good either, since this brings me back to writing `register<myclass>()` over and over.

   So is there a more conviniant way?
   (During the pondering and writing of this I came up with inheriting from a template class. If polimorphism works with template classes with different instantiation parameters. Otherwise I have to use an Interface class, wrap it in a template and Inherit from that )
2. The second question is I have different classes derived from my interface class. However they have members which are not defined in the Interface. I would like to store a functionpointer to a member function, how do I do this? The type has to accept different base classes, but the rest of the function signature is the same (see example below)

   ```
   class A : public interface {
        void myFunc()
   };

   class A : public interface {
        void yourFunc()
   };

   whatType* a = &A::myFunc;
   whatType* b = &B::yourFunc;
   ```

Comment: One question at a time please. Each SO post is a question.

Comment: sorry about that however the second question is closely related to the problem of the first question. I need those pointers so that one module can handle several to it realted events (the interface is only intended for one). If however someone would have offered a different approach to the eventhandler problem, I might have no reason to find a solution to the second problem. Since this explanation is weak and the coupling not that thight I will ask to questions in the future, however the question is asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> //is static (pure) virtual possible?

No

[CRTP (Curiously recurring template pattern)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to the rescue

```
template <class Derived>
class myInterface {
public:
    ...
    virtual *myInterface builder() = 0; 

    Derived* buildDerived() 
    { 
         return dynamic_cast<Derived*>(builder());
    }

};
```

Comment: thanks a lot. now i know the name to read up on it and know that the guess i came up with after pondering is somewhat right. Can you answer the second question as well so I can accept your answer and close the question?

Comment: @ted: sorry, I don't feel inclined to answer 'all' the rest :) You might create smaller, separate questions in the future; as long as the questions are worthwhile, you'll get better answers, more upvotes -> more attention. Plus: the answers are easier to find for future users.

Comment: Agreed. You should post questions regarding individual, isolated issues. A question about an entire design is overly broad and too localised.

Comment: Fine I guess I learned a lesson today. On another note, the flaw that comes to midn with the above answer is, that i can't hide the builder in the class, since I have to call it. And I either need an instance or a static funciton. And static functions cant  be virtual (see answer from 0902horn)

Comment: @ted: which is exactly why I think you needed to know this critical pattern. You can painlessly leverage this pattern to get what you want, but it is not easy with the rest of your design choices you already brought to the table. I suggest you take time to design it from scratch, and post any other questions that come up along the way: not the end-result of a 'limited-thinking' design. This is exactly why I wasn't motivated to try to make 'nice approach' fit in with your question. (See also: "What do you to achieve (_not_ how)" and [XY Problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377))

Comment: I tried to put out ther what i want to achieve in the introductory path (before the 1. and 2.) so I could be pointed to another approach. However I highly doubt that someone is so kind as to conceive a system for such a problem for me. I wanted to draw out my current aproach so I could be pointed at small fixes for the approach to avoid my "problem", a completly new approach or simply the question I asked. Thank you for reading throuhg my wall of text anyway and comming up with one clever answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Static member functions do not take **this** pointer as the first parameter while non-static member functions do, so a static member function can be considered as a global function within the specific namespace. That is why you **cannot** write like this:

   > static virtual *myInterface builder() = 0;
2. There is no way to define a function type like that. If there are functions in different classes but with same signature, consider to have a new interface inherited your first interface and add virtual members to the new interface. When you get a base interface pointer, use **dynamic_cast** to get the original type pointer from the base interface pointer, and then call the new member function. Alternately you can try [Boost::Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html). It seems helpful in your situation.

Comment: I am to some extend aware of binding but i wonder how it helps, could i actually bind the member function to this and store a pointer to the bound type? i.e. ( typeof(bind(myA.f1,this)) == typeof(bind(myB.f2,this)) ) is true even though myA and myB are different classes if f1 and f2 have the same signatures?