# Store pointers to memberfunctions of different classes

Tags: c++

I am trying to store pointers to memberfunctions of *different* Classes in C++. What are the possibilities in C++?

I would like to do this:

```
class A {
    T0 f(T1,T2);
};

class B {
    T0 g(T1,T2);
    T0 h(T1,T2);  //interfaces cant be used since the number of functions per class differs.
};

typedef WHATTOPUTHERE type;

type x;
x = A::f;
x = B::h;
```

**Update:** Another Problem is that the code should be continueable like this:

```
B myB;
myB::x(a,b); //not sure about the syntax, should result in myB::h(a,b) being called
```

This means that I can *not* bind at the time I store the pointer, since the instance does not exist (yet).

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work? What do (or don't) you expect to work?

Comment: The question is unclear.  Are you trying to establish a pointer that can point to either this member function or that member function?

Comment: @JohnDibling yes, I tried to clarify it, see the (pseudo)code I added. Certainly the typedef would look different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function objects to encapsulate your function pointers should work.

[boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/function.html) is one option, maybe something like this:

```
class SomeObj
{
public:
   void SetInt(int i);
};

SomeObj myObject;
std::vector<boost::function> memberFuncs;
// in the template arg to boost::bind specify the function type
// _1 here denotes late binding so you can pass whatever value you want when invoked
// you could simply bind a parameter as a variable or literal instead
memberFuncs.push_back(boost::bind<void(int)>(&SomeObj::SetInt, &myObject, _1));
memberFuncs[0](42); // myObject->SetInt(42);
```

Untested/uncompiled code disclaimer this is just for a general idea.

Comment: well I will fail at the bind part, I dont have actual instances at the time i generate the pointers. But the direction seems to be good.

Comment: You should be able to wrap it in `template<typename ClassType, typename FuncType>` ... also if you have access to C++11 features in your compiler K-ballo brings up an excellent point that there is `std::function` and `std::bind` now defined in `<functional>`

Comment: thanks for the pseudocode, i still have the issue with the early bind. Is there a way to omit the bind and supply a instance reference upon calling/executing the code? e.g. memberFuncs.push_back(...); X myX; memberFuncs[0](&myX,42).?

Comment: With `bind` this isn't actually very long: `std::bind(&X::f, x)` will do fine, and it's convertible to `std::function<T0(T1,T2)>`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you want to pass an object pointer into the function that would be as simple as adding another parameter in the bind call ... lol as Kerrek SB comment example shows above.

Comment: @Ted: `bind(&X::f, _1)`. `_1` is a placeholder for the first argument to be passed in. Though, you'll now need a vector for each possible class from which you're getting function pointers, since each bind object will now need an extra argument (the object the function shall be called on) and that argument is of different type each time. If I had a real computer handy, I'd write an answer that is able to ignore that restriction.

Comment: @AJG85 The idea is, that at the moment where i store the function pointer (the push_back line) I dont have an instance of the object. I would like to create the object just in time (when I want to call the function) and then call the function on that object. However i cant just wrap that. Consider this: from the example in the question I store pointers to B::g und B::h. I want to run those functions later. I check and see I have no Instance of B so I create one and run B::g on that. Now I want to run B::h, I see that I already have an instance of B and run B::h on that.

Comment: @Xeo: I still have to read up on bind. I only partly follow on the vector, i see why it is necessary, however it would conflict with my intentions of having one type of pointer for different classes. I would be greatly interested in a way to avoid the vector for each possible class. Could it work if I assume that all classes have a common base (even though it is not an interface) and could I call my functions without downcasting/would there be a costefficient ay to downcast other than trying all possible classtypes?

Comment: @ted: Take a look at [this](http://ideone.com/H49gO). Not very clean, not very nice to the user, but it works. Note however, that it can be improved *a lot*. Though, the weak point is obviously the enumeration. I hope that will give you a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

One possible implementation (using C++11) can easily be done using std::function and a lambda like this:

```
typedef std::function<void(int)> FunctionType;

SomeClass someClass;

FunctionType func = [&someClass](int argument)
{
    someClass.SomeMemberFunction(argument);
};
```

Comment: can you give me a hint were to read up on this? The syntax with the [] confuses me since I know those only as opperator/array index access

Comment: That's the lambda introducer and tells the compiler that you are defining a lambda function. You can read about that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293603.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To have a pointer to Fred::f(char, float) you need this sort of pointer:

```
int (Fred::*)(char,float)
```

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for, to clarify i have **different** Base classes. I want to store Fred::* and Tina::* in one type. I will clarify my question

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your particular question is that there is no type that you can add to the typedef and make the code compile. The reason is that member function pointers take a hidden argument of the type of the class form which they are obtained. The type of that hidden argument will be different when you take the address of a member function from `A` or `B`.

The next question is whether it makes sense or not from a design perspective, considering that you cannot apply the function pointer `A::f` to an instance of type `B`, what is the point of considering member pointers of `A` and `B` together?

Now, there are possible workarounds for this particular problem (if it makes sense in your case, but I would first review the design) that involve performing type-erasure on the function pointer to remove the hidden argument and generate an object that is callable with the given set of arguments and return type that is common to all of the member functions. This is already done inside `std::function` (alternatively `boost::function` if your compiler does not support C++11), as has been suggested before:

```
A a_instance;
std::function< T0 (T1,T2) > f( std::bind( &A::f, &a_instance, _1, _2 ) );
T0 r = f( T1(), T2() );
```

Note that part of the trick is that `std::bind` *binds* the member function pointer with the pointer to the instance, filling in the hidden argument, while leaving the other two arguments unbound. At this point, because the result of `bind` does no longer depend on the type of the first argument, *type-erasure* can be applied removing `A` from the type of the resulting object.

Comment: Thank you. What you said is basically right, however it has been said before and  I think I can follow. However I see no new concepts. And I think my Problem is a bit trickier. I cant use the "wrapper" trick (at least that easy) since I would like to create the actual instances just in time.

Comment: @ted: And how do you plan on knowing whether the pointer stored in the *generic* refers to type `A` or `B`? You should really state the problem to solve and then you will get help for that, if you state your intended solution (I really doubt this would be a solution, even if you could that you can't for the reasons stated above) BTW, the syntax for your edit would be `myB.*x(a,b)`, but that will only work if `x` is a `B::*`

Comment: @ted: Also, while you consider that the answer does not add anything new, I think it does, it explains why you cannot do what you ask for, because there is a hidden type argument, which I am not sure you have clear: the type of the pointer includes all shown arguments (`T1`,`T2`), the return type (`T0`) **and** the type of the implicit `this` argument (`A` or `B`).

Comment: (hope i got your name right): I tried to explain my whole problem and the way I tried to solve it in other questions (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082450/c-factory-pattern http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093704/c-module-based-event-handling-system) however the answers were unsatisfactory / I was told about and XY-question. I am trying to avoid fast delegates (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx), since the code is old and i hoped for better ways with cpp0x.

Comment: On the "how do I plan to know whether the pointer stored refers to type A or B", the answer is I am trying to not have to know. Lets say I store a factory method along with the pointer. The factory method is called in a wrapper to create the object and the memberfunction pointer wil then be used on the created object. (Guess I have to jiggle a little bit with this, maybe I have to put the factory method into a trampolin function so i dont have to worry about the actual return type), but in general I am interested on how to achieve this.

Comment: Another idea would be adding an interface and downcasting. This way I could store the class pointers all in the same type, however my memberfunctions would not have to be in the interface (see reasoning in question).  Thanks for your additional input which i found very valuable.

Comment: @ted: If you need to store the factory together with the member pointer create an interface for the wrapper and perform type erasure on it in a similar way to what `std::function` does